# can I use lastordefault or firstordefault in this query ?. How can?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var Grdquery = from db in db.V_Salaries
.Where(i => i.InOut_Flag == 0 && i.Year == cariyil).OrderByDescending(i => i.Id)
 orderby db.Worker_Name, db.Year_Name
 select new { db.Id, };

foreach (var row in Grdquery)
{
    DataRow r = Table.NewRow();
    r["Id"] = row.Id;//0
    Table.Rows.Add(r);
 }
```

There are 45 staff. Each employee has at least one salary record for this year. But 10 personnel have 2 salaries.
All the records come out in my query below. No problem with single records. But I want the last record of the staff with 2 records.
How can we solve it?

Comment: How to determine *the last record of the staff*? Is there any date column or is the ID always up-counting? Could you provide three to five data examples? In that case we could model a query based on the data and not reverse engineer the data structure from your not working query.

Comment: Year_Name Receipt_Date Worker_Name Salary Worker_Code Id
2019 1.01.2019 Erdan Birol 1829.00 7 94
2019 1.08.2019 Erkan Mendeşağlı 2434.00 71 141
2019 1.09.2019 Erkan Mendeşağlı 2434.00 71 145
2019 1.01.2019 Fatma Dönmez 1872.53 8 103
2019 1.01.2019 Gurbet Samsa 2700.00 14 104
2019 1.08.2019 Mahmut Yılmaz 4000.00 59 142
2019 1.01.2019 Mahmut Yılmaz 3300.00 59 93

Comment: Could you update your question to add the sample data? That makes it much easier than  reading from a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can group all salaries by persons `Id`:

```
var grouped = Grdquery.GroupBy(g => g.Id)
    .Select(a = new {Id = a.Key, Salaries = a.Select(b => b).ToList()})
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you would have 1 register per worker and the higger id, is newer so it will be the last salary Id and in 1 salary

Grdquery.Where(i => i.InOut_Flag == 0 && i.Year == cariyil).GroupBy(g => g.Worker_Id,(Key,a)=>a.OrderByDescending(b=>b.id).FirstOrDefault()).OrderBy(x=>x.Worker_Name).ThenBy(x=>x.Year_Name).Select(x=>x.Id);

Comment: OK. thank you so much. it happened this way. List<V_Salaries> Grdquery = db.V_Salaries.Where(i => i.InOut_Flag == 0 && i.Year == cariyil)
                .OrderBy(x => x.Worker_Name).ThenBy(x => x.Year_Name)
                .GroupBy(g => g.Worker_Code, (Key, a) => a.OrderByDescending(b => b.Id).FirstOrDefault())
                .ToList();